# INSERT INTO sqlsrv_query statement not working

Tags: php, sql-server

When working with the sqlsrv_query command I can request data from the MSSQL server.
This works
But!

When I want to add data it returns the error [error:array].

The code I use for this is:

```
$tsql= "INSERT INTO dbo.VERLOF_events (id,
                username,
                soort,
                afdeling,
                description,
                evdate,
                trdate) 
                VALUES
                (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                $var = array('', $username, $soort, $afdeling,     $description, $evdate, $trdate);
                if (!sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql, $var))
                     {
                die('Error: ' . sqlsrv_errors());
                     }
                echo "1 record added";
```

The array values are set in the POST statement.

```
$afdeling = $row['Afdeling'];
$submit = @$_POST['submit'];
$description = @$_POST["description"];
$evdate = @$_POST["evdate"];
$trdate = @$_POST["trdate"];
$username = @$_SESSION['username'];
$soort = @$_POST['Dagen'];
```

Why does it return the array error?
I looked it up but could not find the problem returning the error.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `sqlsrv_errors()` _returns an array_. To see its contents, `print_r(sqlsrv_errors())` instead of trying to output it directly in `die()`.

Comment: Change `die('Error: ' . sqlsrv_errors());` to `die('Errors: ' . print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), TRUE);` to get the error messages.

Comment: Output: 

Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'VERLOF_events' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'VERLOF_events' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF. ) ) Error: 1

So the problem is that need to set the IDENTITY_INSERT to on?

Comment: So SQL Server doesn't like you trying to use an empty string in `id`, assuming that's the PK column. Just omit that column from the `INSERT` statement and the bound params.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is probably you're trying to add an empty value in the id field. If you set identity on it with auto-numbering, you don't need to include it in your query :

```
$tsql= "INSERT INTO dbo.VERLOF_events (
            username,
            soort,
            afdeling,
            description,
            evdate,
            trdate) 
            VALUES
            (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            $var = array($username, $soort, $afdeling,     $description, $evdate, $trdate);
            if (!sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql, $var))
                 {
            die('Error: ' . sqlsrv_errors());
                 }
            echo "1 record added";
```

Comment: Alright, I listened to your advice but now i got something new. error message: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 07002 [SQLSTATE] => 07002 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error ) ) Error: 1

Comment: My bad, I forgot to remove the question mark. I editted the code, should work now